# Safest way to write into /etc from php application?

Tags: php, linux, apache2, rights

What is the safest way to achieve storing a config file into /etc after entering the settings on a php application running in Apache2 ?

I have a daemon reading its config at startup from a file I stored into /etc/mydaemon/main.conf (thought it was the best place to store its settings).

Now I want to have a php application allowing users to change its setup via elegant webpages. But how can I get the rights to write/overwrite this file without compromising the server's security?

Comment: That type of configuration is better kept in a database than in the system config file.

Answer (score 0):

If the Apache user (`www-data`) can write or modify `/etc` all the system is compromised.

If any user of the PHP application can change the demon's configuration the behaviour may be a mess. You told about "users", changing simultaneously that config file.

As @quentin says use a database if you need persistence; or an application file (not in `/etc` or other system directory).

Comment: To explain further, I'm conceiving an automated system based on a Raspberry Pi, something packaged, where you would at first run enter the setup of the surrounding modules that would be stored once, I see that as you would setup your network parameters, once. When I say "users", that means one user per end device, it's not intended to be multi-user. I often see packaged appliances relying on Linux or BSD where you have a web admin page allowing you to change network parameters, that are written into /etc/interfaces, I was hoping to do something like this

Comment: http://www.webmin.com is a good example; but Webmin uses its own webserver and the system users. Of course you can asign permissions (owner, group or all) in `/etc` to the apache user (**www-data** in Debian systems), but is a dangerous hole.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, didn't know that, I thought it was lying over Apache. What is then the good path for such a config file? I was always thinking all conf should go to /etc